# MySQL: How to order by rating and distance?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a request (at the PHP-code):

```
        $sql = 
            "SELECT id_, name_, status, starsCount, photoFilename, "
            . "( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$lastPosition_lat') ) * 
                cos( radians( objLatitude ) ) * 
                cos( radians( objLongitude ) - 
                radians('$lastPosition_long') ) + "
            . "sin( radians('$lastPosition_lat') ) * 
                sin( radians( objLatitude ) ) ) ) 
                AS distance 
                FROM markets "
            . "ORDER BY distance ASC, starsCount DESC "
            . "LIMIT $itemsWatched,15";
```

I need to get nearby markets sorted by rating(stars between 1 and 5).

Alternatively, I can get the minimum and maximum range of the current user to another portion markets and in second query get sorted by rating. But I think, that this way will be very slow.

**Can you help me to get list of markets sorted by distance and rating by fast query?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. I was remake my idea and found answer by myself.

```
    $sql = 
            "SELECT MIN(
            ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$lastPosition_lat') ) * 
                cos( radians( objLatitude ) ) * 
                cos( radians( objLongitude) - 
                radians('$lastPosition_long') ) + 
            sin( radians('$lastPosition_lat') ) * 
                sin( radians( objLatitude ) ) ) )) 
                AS minDistance, 
            MAX( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$lastPosition_lat') ) * 
                cos( radians( objLatitude ) ) * 
                cos( radians( objLongitude) - 
                radians('$lastPosition_long') ) + 
            sin( radians('$lastPosition_lat') ) *
                sin( radians( objLatitude ) ) ) ) 
                AS maxDistance 
            FROM markets                                            
            LIMIT $itemsWatched,15";
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $resQ = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $minDis = "0";
    $maxDis = "0";
    if ($resQ){
        $minDis = $resQ[0];
        $maxDis = $resQ[1];
    }
    $sql = 
            "SELECT id_, name_, status, starsCount, photoFilename, "
            . "( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$lastPosition_lat') ) * 
                cos( radians( objLatitude ) ) * 
                cos( radians( objLongitude ) - 
                radians('$lastPosition_long') ) + "
            . "sin( radians('$lastPosition_lat') ) * 
                sin( radians( objLatitude ) ) ) ) 
                AS distance 
                FROM markets "
            . "HAVING distance BETWEEN '$minDis' AND '$maxDis' "
            . "ORDER BY starsCount DESC "
            . "LIMIT $itemsWatched,15";
```

**Now it works perfectly.**
What we do? We get, for example, items 10-25 from database(LIMIT), calculating MIN and MAX distance from phone(user) for this portion. So, user always firstly see markets with best rating(popularity), when incriminate distance from them self to markets (every 15 markets user see firstly markets with best rating).
**Hope this helps people, who want to sort objects by distance and rating dynamically!**

Answer (score 0):

If i get your problem right, you could always limit the distance (where distance < X km) AND make a simple formula to calculate a rating/distance ratio, in this case, you would like to show High ratings, and nearby first? you will have a formula like:  distance / ratings, order asc.

Comment: My situation is more simple, than you may think. Rating is a count of watches (users unique visits [INT]). So, I was trying to sort by distance and watches count (INT values). I can't now to change database and insert new attribute like "distance/rating" and so on formulas. :( Sorry for my russian.

Comment: And if I try to calc by some formul, it will be looks like a variant with min and max distances (I was write about it in question), so it will be not powerful, as I see. And I don't have a fixed radius for getting items. I getting items by number of already watched items: $itemsWatched

Answer (score 0):

If you find that your query runs slowly, which seems like a reasonable thing to expect when performing a complex calculation over your entire table, I would suggest limiting the number of rows that need to have their distance calculated. Decide on a reasonable definition of what you consider "nearby", and add a WHERE clause to reduce the rows that go into that calculation.

```
"WHERE
    objLatitude BETWEEN ".
       $lastPosition_lat - $nearby_distance
    ." AND ".
       $lastPosition_lat + $nearby_distance
"AND
    objLatitude BETWEEN ".
       $lastPosition_long - $nearby_distance
    ." AND ".
       $lastPosition_long + $nearby_distance
```

This may not return anything if nothing is within the rectangle this will define, but in that case there just isn't anything nearby, and you can either tell your users that, or maybe try running the query again with a larger "nearby distance".

Comment: I have no fixed nearby distance.